# Why $\vec{r}$ is commonly use for vector equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, plane-curves

I'm wondering why $\vec{r}$ is commonly use in mathematics (vector calculus, line integrals) and physics for denote the vector equation.

**Edit/Added clarification**: I'm wondering why the *letter* $r$ is commonly use in mathematics (vector calculus, line integrals) and physics for denote the vector equation.

Comment: Vectors have a magnitude and a direction. The arrow helpfully reinforces the idea that $r$ is more than just a number but also has a direction.

Comment: Are you asking about the arrow (see the previous comment by Daniel Rust) or are you asking about the choice of letter $r$?

Comment: I believe the letter $r$ is chosen because the vector is an element of $\mathbb{R}^d$, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm asking about the choice of letter $r$. Sorry for the possible Misunderstanding.

Comment: I conjecture that physicists (never seen much of that in mathematics) often use $r$ for "radius vector". But I have nothing to back that up.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've been trained up as a physicist and I backup your claim.

Comment: I think all anyone can do is speculate, since it's just a convention, and there's no meeting that got together and decided on it (if there were, we'd probably be able to check the minutes of said meeting to find a definite answer). I think these are all really good guesses though.

Comment: Though obviously false, the following explanation has been popular with my students: It is a verbal joke (which only works in English): since the vector gives your location from the origin, it tells you where you "are".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the letter $r$ used in physics (usually denoted as $\mathbf{r}$ or less commonly $\vec{r}$) to denote the position vector of a particle. It is also called the ***r****adius vector* and may be that's why $r$ is more commonly used. In math, when the variable $r$ is used, it's not really for any particular reason. Also I haven't seen $\mathbf{r}$ or $\vec{r}$ used in pure math (probably used more in some applied math fields which are related to physics).

Answer (score 1):

When we write $\vec r$, the "arrow" above the variable $r$ helps distinguish the vector $r = \langle x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\rangle$ from the $n-$ tuple $r = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$, and helps as well to distinguish a variable representing a vector from a variable representing a scalar value.

The use of the variable $r$ to denote (name) a vector is arbitrary.

Comment: I don't understand the words "vector equation" in the title. :+)

Answer (score 1):

Vectors can be regarded as "arrows" in 3D space. So, we put little arrows over the symbols, to help distinguish vectors from plain numbers. There are several other common notations. Some people like to underline the the symbol, or put a little squiggle under it, and others (like me) just use bold letters.

If you're asking why people use the letter "r" (as opposed to some other letter), I don't know why. Personally, I use "$\mathbf x$" more than "$\mathbf r$".

Maybe people use "$\mathbf r$" because $r$ is a natural symbol for the "radial distance" from the origin to a point. So, if we denote  the corresponding position vector by $\mathbf r$, then we have the nice relationship $r = \Vert \mathbf r \Vert$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is actually *not* commonly used in all areas of mathematics. It is used in physics and occasionally in mathematical areas which deal with problems motivated by physics (e.g. differential equations).

There vectors are most commonly just column vectors or 'arrows' in an n-dimensional space. This is indicated by the arrow on the top. The reason to use this, is to make it easier to distinguish between vectors and scalars.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the use of $\vec{r}$  specifically denotes a vector that points from the origin to a position in real space. As opposed to $\vec{v}$, which usually denotes an arbitrary vector that could represent any vector quantity (or in the case of physics, velocity), $\vec{r}$ carries the implication that the vector represents a position in real space.

I believe this comes from the fact that it is a position in **r**eal space.

$$\vec{r}\in\mathbb{R}^d$$

It is also a possibiity that it stands for **r**adial vector, because it is a vector that is radial to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because $\vec r \cdot\vec r=|r|^2$ so when one is using polar forms of co-ordinates (natural for forces etc originating at a point source) the designation of the vector as $\vec r$ takes its cue from the magnitude $|r|$.

But there are many situations where other notations are used.