# Why do we use r to represent vector-valued functions?

Tags: calculus, notation, vectors

Many standard calculus texts use **r** as the default function name when defining vector-valued functions, e.g.,

$\textbf{r}(t)=\langle x(t),y(t),z(t)\rangle$.

For scalar-valued functions, we default to *f*, which makes sense because it is the initial letter of the word "function".  However, I can not think of an analogous reason as to why we might use **r** for vector-valued functions.

Does anyone have an insight on the history of this convention?

Comment: My guess is that it comes from latin *radius* (ray)

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468283/why-vecr-is-commonly-use-for-vector-equation).

Comment: Well, its length is $r(t)$, which would match with the word "radius", which is appropriate. Alternately, you've used $x,y,z$ already, where do you go? We tend to want $a,b,c,d$ free to use in different ways in different contexts; $e$ and $i$ are taken as mathematical constants; $f,g,h$ are taken by functions defined in context; $j,k,m,n$ are usually integers; $l$ is generally forbidden by similarity to $1$; $o$ is generally forbidden by similarity to $0$; $p$ is usually an integer or a polynomial; $q,r,s$ are free; $t$ is usually a time; $u,v,w$ are free.

Comment: So you have basically six choices among lowercase letters. Pick one.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo - thanks for the link.  Not sure how I missed that one!